# Selenium Python - More compact or Pythonic way of inputting Username and Password?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I need to log into a website and I already have the following code, which works fine:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_name('uname')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
username.send_keys('username'), password.send_keys('password', Keys.RETURN)
```

Right now, the username and password are hard-coded into the program, but I will eventually require the user to supply both for security reasons. Is there a way to make what I have written more compact or more Pythonic? I'm trying to stay as close to PEP8 as best I can for my own benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is completely *Pythonic* unless there are *runtime* errors.

Having said that, from [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) point of view there are a couple of concerns as follows:

- Presumably, you will initiate locating the *username* after invoking `get()`. So ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()`  and invoke `send_keys()` thereafter as follows:

  ```
  driver.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "'uname'"))).send_keys('username')
  driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('password')
  ```
- Moreover, I would suggest to avoid an attempt to `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` unless you are left out with any other option. Ideally, you should invoke `click()` on the <kbd>Login</kbd> or <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('cssSelector').click()
  # incase the elements are with in a <form>
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('cssSelector').submit()
  ```

Comment: I like the idea of using WebDriverWait before getting the username element, but what is the reasoning behind finding the sign in button versus just using Keys.Return? I'm still learning a lot about Python through this project, which is rather intimidating because I'm doing it for my work even though this is not at all what I was hired for. But me doing this will increase my and one of my coworker's productivity.

Comment: @Auske I didn't get your question, can you come again? Was it on `WebDriverWait` or `Keys.Return`?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking why not just use `Keys.RETURN`?

Comment: @Auske One of the main reason is the `Login` or `Sign In` button can be _Javascript_ enabled and even can have _onclick_ events which will only fire with invoking `click()`.

Comment: I just tried to use `WebDriverWait` in my code, but I couldn't get it to work. It would timeout trying to find the element. But I did go ahead and change `Keys.RETURN`.
Here are my new lines:

`print('Finding username and password and sending both')`
`driver.find_element_by_name('uname').send_keys(username)`
`driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)`
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("bttn").click()`
`print('Logging in')`

Comment: @Auske Glad to be able to help you !!! If you have any question on `WebDriverWait` feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.